# How do I make SQL changes without leaving the page?

Tags: php, sql

I have a page which lists out book reviews which are pulled from an SQL database, and listed out in a loop with PHP.

The text of some of the reviews may contain *"spoilers"* (meaning the review reveals plot points and may "ruin the surprise" for would-be readers.)

I want to have a link/button which a reader clicks, saying "This Review Contains Spoilers". When they **click** it, there's a field in the SQL record for that review, which gets incremented. But, without leaving the page, as the viewer will continue reading the reviews.

Comment: as with everything related to changing a page without leaving it: AJAX

Comment: AJAX call to a php script that you pass the book id to it and it can increment the value based on that id in the db.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of Ajax, exactly of XMLHttpRequest (abbr.: XHR). jQuery is a good framework that has cross-browser support for the different XMLHttpRequest calls. With this technique you could send a http request to a server at any time on the loaded page you want. E. g. when the user clicks the spoiler. For more information about it see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest For more information about jQuery please see here: http://www.jquery.com